# Return partial text from output, removing the text from another query

Tags: t-sql, partial

I need to return some data which contains the values I need, plus more. How can i retrieve the data, excluding the values that I don't need, which exists elsewhere?

Or if this is not possible, the variations of values that needs to be removed are from 5 possibilities, therefore can I 'replace' any occurrence of the 5?

For example:

```
    TABLE1

    ID    ITEM
    -------------------------
    1     AAA:CAR
    2     BBB:PLANE
    3     AAA:BIKE
    4     BBB:TRAIN
    5     CCC:BUS
```

I think the below will remove AAA: from the result

```
    SELECT ITEM REPLACE(ITEM, 'AAA:', '')
    FROM TABLE1
```

Assume this would return

```
    ITEM
    ----------
    CAR
    BBB:PLANE
    BIKE
    BBB:TRAIN
    CCC:BUS
```

However I want to replace AAA: and BBB: and CCC: with '' where AAA: or BBB: or CCC: exist elsewhere, for example here:

```
    TABLE2

    ID    THING
    -----------------
    1     AAA:
    2     BBB:
    3     CCC:
    4     DDD:
    5     EEE:
```

For example:

```
SELECT ITEM REPLACE(ITEM, '/* where THING ID exists in TABLE2 BETWEEN 1 and 5 */', '')
FROM TABLE1
```

Or if this is not possible, to state any variation that may exist to be replaced:

```
SELECT ITEM REPLACE(ITEM, '/* AAA: or BBB: or CCC: or DDD: or EEE: */', '')
FROM TABLE1
```

Any help with this would be very appreciated from this SQL newby!

Comment: Would it be possible, to cut away the all characters before the `:`? Or do you really need a list of explicitly stated replacments?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this query ([sqlfiddle: online query](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c6f2f/12/0)):

```
select t1.ID, ISNULL(REPLACE(t1.Item, t2.Thing, ''), t1.Item) AS THING
from table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2 on (CHARINDEX(t2.Thing, t1.Item) != 0);
```